# I need to set up a mobile app, based on an existing website

Tags: html, mobile, web

first off sorry for asking this question if it's something that has been covered already. 
What I'm looking to do is build a mobile app that will run on multiple platforms that is based on an existing website. This will need to be a small app that is meant to keep people updated on upcoming events, and schedules and help make donations easier for a non profit sports team.
I have no idea where to start... I've seen things that directed me to the jquerymobile site, phonegap, phonegap build, and I gotta be honest I'm a bit lost.

This is what I need from the app:
- It won't carry every page from our site, just a few key pages... home page, calendar, schedule, donations, etc.
- I want the info in the app to update if/when the website is updated.

### - Again, it will need to be used on multiple platforms (ios, WP8, android, blackberry)

I know I basically need a site "wrapper", which is fine. But I have no idea how to make one. Phonegap build is asking for "web assets", but I don't know how to get those. Also, they say I will need an Mac OS system to create an ios app? That's not an option here. 
Will I need to create a mobile (HTML5) site before I can create the app?
Any help will be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Answer (score 1):

I think you have 2 options that will help you with phonegap.

The first one, very easy, is just to use phonegap to make an application that open your website in the application. It's called in phonegap the inappbrowser. With this, you just have to modify the website and everything will work on every phone. But you will have to adjust a little bit your website for the mobile.

The second one, is to create a similar website in html5, css and javascript in a www folder that will be the same for every platform. But this will take more time.

You will need a macos to deploy a ios app

If you still have question, don't hesitate

Comment: Would it be best to create a mobile site first, and use that?
As far as using phonegap, is phonegap build the way to go, or should I download and use the software?

What is the first step to take using either method you mentioned? That is the main area I am getting hung up on. 

Thanks a lot for your help!